# Call to class from different eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two different eclipse plugin projects and I want to call to class from proj1 in proj2,
what are the steps that I should do?

I have tried to do it with adding a project proj1 to project2 with the tab right click on project properties and in the tab project ,without success .it doesnt know it?

Comment: That is exactly how it is done. Try 'project clean'

Comment: when I try to add the project I getting this message:  Build path contains duplicate entry: 'proj1' for project 'proj2'

Comment: Main menue: 'Project' than click on 'Clean ...' select 'Clean all projects' and press 'OK'

Comment: Check your buildpath (where you added proj1.

Comment: Both projects cannot depend on each other (circular dependencies are not allowed by eclipse)

Comment: The clean helps thank you ,how can i close this treat ?

Comment: I added my comment as an Answer. You may simply accept the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Eclipse get confused or does not use your changed configuration by itself.
Often it helps to force eclipse to build all projects again.

Main menue: 'Project' than click on 'Clean ...' select 'Clean all projects' and press 'OK'

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with plug-in projects, they can only rely on other plug-ins and .jar files according to their plug-in manifest files.  Open proj2's MANIFEST.MF file in the Plug-In Manifest Editor and add proj1 as a Required Plug-in from the Dependency tab.